# apache rewrite on virtualhost won't work

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, virtualhost

having problems to configure my apache virtualhost to work togheter with mod_rewrite. I have been enabling mod_rewrite `a2enmod rewrite` and I was creating the conf file for my virtualhost

```
ServerName wpa.myserver.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/wordpress"
    <Directory "/var/www/wordpress">
       AllowOverride All
       Options +FollowSymLinks
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
    </Directory>
```

On apache reload I'm getting error 500 and in my log file  I'm getting the following

```
Invalid command 'Rewrite', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included...
```

htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Rewrite test.html index.html
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

PS. previously I was trying to use webmin to configure my virtualhost

Comment: There's no "Rewrite" in the code you show,  it must be elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rewrite test.html index.html
```

`Rewrite` is not  a valid statement.

You probably meant `RewriteRule`.